# How do flink proccess two stream connect by key, but without matched key

Tags: stream, apache-flink

I am new to flink. I have two `DataStream` generated by `FlatMapFunction`, and I want to connect them by same key, what is one steam's element cant find matched key in other stream, what will flink do to this element , will it store in state forever?  every flatmap will generate a bulk of elements, and I want to finish join on every flatmap.

what is the normal way to join two stream that maybe have unmatched element? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flink's online training site has a [tutorial on the topic of expiring state](https://training.ververica.com/exercises/rideEnrichment-processfunction.html) that you might find helpful. There the approach is to use a ProcessFunction to implement the join by hand. In this example a timer is used to clear unmatched state. An alternative would be to use Flink's [State TTL mechanism](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl).

Some of Flink's built-in join functions also have a notion of narrowing the scope of the join so as to avoid indefinite state retention -- see [the docs on joining](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html) for more details.

You can also [use Flink SQL to do joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html). You can either bound these joins explicitly in the query so they don't retain state indefinitely, or [configure the SQL engine to expire state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/query_configuration.html#idle-state-retention-time) for you.

Comment: Can I continue push forword the expire element to next operator?

Comment: Yes, when a timer fires a ProcessFunction can forward the expired element to the next operator. It could also use a side output to send the expired element to a different downstream operator for special processing.